# Google Map API : Route with more than one transport mode

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I have a requirement in Google Map. I have Start and End Point. In between them, there are few waypoints. I have to connect start and end point through the waypoints. This is feasible with google map api and i have done this. But in one case, i have to draw rail route, that is, two waypoints will be connected by rail route. So, i have a have route consisting of car route and rail route.

Sample: Consider A, B, C and D are the places.

A - Start Point, B- WayPoint 1, C - Waypoint 2, D - End Point

A to B - Car route

B to C - Rail route

C to D - Car route

How am i supposed to do this.??

Please guide me.!!

Comment: you have used https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple?authuser=2

Answer (score -1):

I hope this example used for you  **And must be register YOUR_API_KEY**
also **change** your location latitude and longitude **flightPlanCoordinates** javascript variable value

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple?authuser=2

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Simple Polylines</title>
        <style>
          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
          #map {
            height: 100%;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>

          // This example creates a 2-pixel-wide red polyline showing the path of William
          // Kingsford Smith's first trans-Pacific flight between Oakland, CA, and
          // Brisbane, Australia.

          function initMap() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 3,
              center: {lat: 0, lng: -180},
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            });

            var flightPlanCoordinates = [
              {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
              {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
              {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
              {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
            ];
            var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
              path: flightPlanCoordinates,
              geodesic: true,
              strokeColor: '#FF0000',
              strokeOpacity: 1.0,
              strokeWeight: 2
            });

            flightPath.setMap(map);
          }
        </script>
        <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Make separate requests for the different segments (a directions request can only have one travel mode)

Comment: @geocodezip i have only two cordinates, start and end point. Intermidate points i need to get to draw a line only in sea. Can u give me some idea to get them.?